# What should be done to get the Persistent Set filtered using a query condition

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, one-to-many, persistent-set

I'm having two DAO classes `FeeGroup` and `FeeHeading` like this

```
class FeeGroup {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<FeeHeading> feeHeadings;
    private booelan isActive;
    //getters & setters
}
class FeeHeading {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private FeeGroup feeGroup;
    private booelan isActive;
    //getters & setters
}
```

This is the `HQL` query to fetch results based on `isActive` values of both `FeeHeading` and `FeeGroup`.

```
select fg.feeHeadings 
from FeeHeading fh 
join fh.feeGroup fg
where fg.isActive = 1
and fg.isOptional = 0
and fh.isActive = 1
and fg.id = 78
```

The `FeeGroup` with id 78 is having 10 `FeeHeading`s under it and only one heading is having isActive as 1. The current query is returning 10 records even if I have given the filter condition as `fh.isActive = 1`. But when I change my query to

```
select fh.name 
from FeeHeading fh 
join fh.feeGroup fg
where fg.isActive = 1
and fg.isOptional = 0
and fh.isActive = 1
and fg.id = 78
```

Only one record is coming which is the only active record. So why I'm not getting a filtered `Set` in the first place even if the condition is given or what should I do in the query to get it filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first statement you are selecting all the `FeeGroups` and returning their associated `FeeHeadings`. You cannot create a sublist of a list querying the parent object. JPA is filtering your query and then must load all the requested objects with there complete elements. If `FeeGroup` meets your requirements (`id` = 78 and `isOptional` = 0 and at least one `FeeHeading` with `isActive` = 1) it must load the complete Group.

In your second query you are selecting the `FeeHeadings`directly, so you can create a sublist of them, because JPA must only create that objects.

**UPDATE**

Not tested so far, but you might test if the following JPQL gives you the desired result:

```
select fh
from FeeHeading fh 
where fh.feeGroup.isActive = 1
and fh.feeGroup.isOptional = 0
and fh.isActive = 1
and fh.feeGroup.id = 78
```

Comment: so even if I give the isActive condition, the Set retrieved from FeeGroup wont be having any impact due to that condition?

Comment: No, because when at least one `FeeHeading` in the `FeeGroup` meet the requirements, the complete `FeeGroup` is loaded by JPA.

Comment: so how to get it filtered from the query itself

Comment: Thanks for the answer but actually we want to fetch the FeeGroups, so that in the later part of code we iterate the FeeGroup and take the Set of FeeHeadings from individual groups and perform the nested iteration to populate a Map.

Comment: Ok, than you have to filter the groups manually. (Hint: do not remove the FeeHeadings from List, when the FeeGroup is still attached to an underlying Transaction, otherwise they will be removed from database)

Comment: the Map is used for display purpose and not for any database activities so even if I filter the headings based on isActive condition while iterating, it won't be causing any problems right?

Answer (score 1):

In first query you select all heading from group in which (group) has at least one heading satisfy the condition. I.e. all 10 headings from your group.

In second query you select only headings which satisfy the condition. I.e. only one heading.